# Should I always use a comma when I include two possible answers in an already complete question?

Tags: commas, questions

Should I always use a comma when I include two possible answers in an already complete question? I've been through this stackexchange for this question, as well as top google hits. Nothing yet. Can I omit the commas in e.g.

- What are these, verbs or nouns?

Seems like you need the comma if you're asking whether "these" are verbs or nouns, rather than asking what these verbs or nouns are. But what about

- Who are you, Tom or Sam?

It seems fairly strange if we're asking Tom or Sam who they are. A better example

- What are they for, class or homework?

The comma seems to work, but is it necessary?

Comment: If you write that sentence without a comma the meaning would still be clear, but it would be a badly punctuated sentence. A comma in such cases is highly desirable.

Comment: A spoken pause, comma or dash prevents misunderstanding the first item as object of the preposition: "What are these flowers for Sue's birthday doing on my desk?" vs. "What are these flower for, Sue's birthday or Beth's promotion? We definitely pause when speaking the latter. The commas are needed in your examples.

Comment: I disagree with 405's first statement. The comma (or something more heavy duty if you want to add a little drama – a dash or ellipsis) is certainly needed in these examples. "What are these CDs or DVDs?" asks a different question from "What are these – /,  CDs or DVDs?" And even where there is little logical scope for ambiguity, the comma is needed to defeat the garden-path problem and aid parsing. "Who are you Tom  (") invites "Just a friend of your daughter's." The pause needs signalling, as DjinnTonic says.

Comment: Consider using a colon instead. It would work in each of your three example sentences, quite possibly better than a comma.